# How to make triangles on the form with shadow?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

As you can see, form have triangles on the left side and right side. And double shadow 0 0 0 2px, 0 0 0 6px. I have implemented this feature with :after and :before, but it broken layout. If you can help me, help please. I'll be glad for any link or article that will solve this issue
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/BeriaFantom/sLkdy0fx/1/

```css
#middle {
  position: relative;
}
#middle-form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#middle-form:after,
#middle-form:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#middle-form::after {
  right: -24px;
  border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
  border-top: 75px solid transparent;
  border-left: 24px solid #1e9baf;
}
#middle-form::before {
  left: -24px;
  border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
  border-top: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 24px solid #1e9baf;
}
```

```html
<div id="middle">

  <div id="middle-form" class='container'>
    <h2>заказать мастера</h2>
    <form action="" class='clear'>
      <input type="text" class='name'>
      <input type="tel" class='tel'>
      <button class="btn-sen">отправить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should come with code you tried. SO is not code giving service..

Comment: Hi Marik - as Leo said, please add a jsfiddle with example code so that we can see how you created the triangles.

Comment: Hi. https://jsfiddle.net/BeriaFantom/sLkdy0fx/1/ It just easy markup. Second, I edit it

Comment: @MarikZuckor I have noted a couple of times now that your questions seem to direct towards a ["give meh teh codez"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question) use of Stack Overflow. You may want to look into [this quick tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what is actually suitable for SO, as we are not exactly [freelancers](https://www.freelancer.co.uk/) to just provide the working code.

Comment: I have noted for now how you you made a big mistake. if you look carefuly on my questions you will understand that i duplicate questions of one topic, because some people dont understand what i want, and desperately offer their non-working solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made changes in your fiddle, check now.

```css
body {background: black;}
#middle {position: relative; width: 300px; margin-left: 100px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #ccc;}
#middle-form {background: #1e9baf none repeat scroll 0 0; height: 128px; position: relative; z-index: 100; border:2px solid #fff; border-width:2px 0;}
#middle:after, #middle:before {background: #1e9baf none repeat scroll 0 0; box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #ccc; content: ""; display: block; height: 90px; position: absolute; top: 19px; transform: rotate(45deg); width: 90px; z-index: 10; border:2px solid #fff;}
#middle::after {right: -48px;}
#middle::before {left: -48px;}
```

```html
<div id="middle">
    <div id="middle-form" class='container'>
        <h2>заказать мастера</h2>
        <form action="" class='clear'>
            <input type="text" class='name'>
            <input type="tel" class='tel'>
            <button class="btn-sen">отправить</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked. But it initial point of changes. It doesnt take shadow. Look at jsfiddle

Comment: double shadow 0 0 0 2px, 0 0 0 6px, but if it hard, dont do this or just 1 level-shadow. it isn't freelance) i hear that with :after and :before it impossible

Comment: @MarikZuckor See my code now, I have changed it.
two shadows doesnt look possible, you can also add border in it, which will give you impact of 2 shadows.

Comment: thank you. could you do height 150px and more narrow width, like 25px? i have something problem with it

Answer (score 1):

i'll go again with the gradients thing

```css
#middle {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: table;
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 0 3em 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray 4px, white 4px, white 6px, #1e9baf 6px, #1e9baf calc(100% - 6px), white calc(100% - 6px), white calc(100% - 4px), gray calc(100% - 4px)) center no-repeat, linear-gradient(70deg, transparent 1.5em, gray 1.5em, gray calc(1.5em + 3px), white calc(1.5em + 3px), white calc(1.5em + 4px), #1e9baf calc(1.5em + 6px)) bottom left no-repeat, linear-gradient(-70deg, transparent 1.5em, gray 1.5em, gray calc(1.5em + 3px), white calc(1.5em + 3px), white calc(1.5em + 4px), #1e9baf calc(1.5em + 6px)) bottom right no-repeat, linear-gradient(-250deg, transparent 1.5em, gray 1.5em, gray calc(1.5em + 3px), white calc(1.5em + 3px), white calc(1.5em + 4px), #1e9baf calc(1.5em + 6px)) top left no-repeat, linear-gradient(250deg, transparent 1.5em, gray 1.5em, gray calc(1.5em + 3px), white calc(1.5em + 3px), white calc(1.5em + 4px), #1e9baf calc(1.5em + 6px)) top right no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(100% - 3em - 8px) 100%, 50.05% 50.05%, 50.05% 50.05%, 50.05% 50.05%, 50.05% 50.05%;
  box-shadow: 0 2.25em 15px -2em white, 0 -2.25em 15px -2em white
}
h2 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}
input,
button {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px -1px #555, inset 0 0 0 2em white;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  margin: 0.5em 0.1em;
  width: 11em;
}
button {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffab00 30%, #fff800);
  padding: 0.2em 3em;
  width: 9.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #A46D02;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white
}
/* demo purpose, show transparency */

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, gray, white, #333, gold, tomato, gray, turquoise, tomato);
}
```

```html
<div id="middle">
  <div id="middle-form" class='container'>
    <h2>заказать мастера</h2>
    <form action="" class='clear'>
      <input placeholder=" Name" type="text" class='name' />
      <input placeholder="☎ Phone" type="tel" class='tel' />
      <button class="btn-sen">отправить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is for me its very rude shadow for users)

Comment: @MarikZuckor not too sure i understand what you mean by 'rude', are you using only chrome ? if so i guess i understand :) .. chrome will improve ....

Comment: @MarikZuckor a pseudo + little blur can help webkit  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YqBOaE

Answer (score 0):

For div with diagonal you can use trasform 2d skew

this is a sample

```
#id_div_diag {
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg); 
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
   transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

the solution is  combination fo more differnt div with different transform